# Schrodinger equation peculiar solution

Tags: homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, hilbert-space, schroedinger-equation, observables

This problem is generated from a problem given in Griffiths "Quantum Mechanics".
The question is as follows:

The initial wavefunction of a particle in an infinite square well is given by
$$\phi(x,0)=Ax(a-x).$$
We are to calculate the expectation values of position Momentum and energy.

If we proceed using the Fourier Series method, its fine but if we substitute the wave function in the original time-independent Schrodinger equation then the result is a bit peculiar.

As the double derivative of the initial wave function with respect to $X =-2aA$, the equation becomes
$$-(1/2m)\cdot(h^2/4\pi^2)\cdot(-2aA)=EAx(a-x),$$
that is,
$$(h^2/4\pi^2)m=Ex(a-x).$$

Now this equation is quite unusual. Certainly there is some problem proceeding in this way. What is it?

Comment: What makes you think that the wavefunction is an eigenfunction of the Hamiltonian in the first place?

Comment: I thought this in the way that the time independent Schrodinger equation is an eigenvalue equation and hence its Solutions also should obey the equation. Now as the solutions of the Schrodinger equation in infinite square well form orthogonal complete set the arbitrary wave function given in the question should be able to be written as the sum of the solutions. Now when I am doing it with the Fourier Series its fine but in this way if I proceed then some mistake occurs

Comment: Please illaborate if i am making any conceptual mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem, as DanielC indicated, is that you've assumed $\phi$ is an eigenstate of the Hamiltonian.  That is you've assumed $\hat{H}\phi = E\phi$, which if you check, you'll see isn't true:
$$\frac{d^2}{d x^2}\left(Ax(a-x)\right)=-2A \neq E\phi.$$
We get to an answer that is not in the form of the eigenvalue equation.  So you can't substitute your wavefunction into the eigenvalue equation, because it isn't an eigenstate!

While the wave function will be expressible as a sum of Hamiltonian eigenstates, any specific sum generally won't be an eigenstate.  Observe this by using some wavefunction $\psi=\phi_1+\phi_2$, where both $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ are eigenstates of the Hamiltonian.
$$\hat{H}\psi = \hat{H}\left(\phi_1+\phi_2\right) = E_1\phi_1 + E_2\phi_2.$$
Again, our result is not of the form $(\text{constant}\times \psi)$, and so this superposition state is not an eigenstate.

Answer (score 1):

That is not the way to find the expectation energy. For an observable $P$ with operator $\hat{P}$, you find the expectation value $\langle P \rangle=\int d\mu~ \psi^{*}\hat{P}\psi$. In your case, $P$ is the energy and $\hat{P}=-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{d^2}{dx^2}$. So you find the expectation energy by $\langle E\rangle=\int dx~\psi^* (-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{d^2\psi}{dx^2})$. The formula which you tried using is for eigenfunctions of the Hamiltonian, which is not true for the case which you gave

Comment: Actually I should have clarified it better in the question,I am only asking about what is the mistake in my steps,I am actually not eager to find the expectaion of energy.

Comment: Kindly learn how to use \langle and \rangle

Comment: @user157588  I have written it in my answer, what you did is valid only for the eigenfunctions of the hamiltonian.